# Exclude tests files from setuptools find packages

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, packaging, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to build a lib without the test files, as described here https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html. In the `pyproject.toml`, I got:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ['lib*']
exclude = ['^.*tests']
```

with this exclude pattern correctly matching the 3 last elements:

```
lib
lib.mod1
lib.mod2
lib.utils
lib.mod1.tests
lib.mod2.tests
lib.utils.tests
```

Yet, when I build with `python -m build` and install the resulting wheel, I still get the  3 test modules in the distribution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using regex syntax. But this is a glob/wildmatch pattern, not regex.

Try this:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ['lib*']
exclude = ['lib*tests']
```

Comment: So that's why! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it does not work. The pattern matching is correct and does pick up the modules to exclude, but they still end-up in the distribution I got with `py -m build` using this lib: https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Maybe it's because this tool is only PEP 517 compliant..

Comment: Hmm - is there any reason you include the tests inside the application code if you don't want them packaged?  Most people prefer to use a [_Tests outside application code_](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code) directory structure in that case.

Comment: So the issue is with `setuptools` and how it includes package data. See: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3260
I'm currently discussing it here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/discussions/3346#user-content-fnref-1-938f4a10938509a2d8b1669f9be008e6 (and learning a lot in the process). 
I was not aware of this standard to put the tests outside; I prefer the one from the scikit packages, e.g. numpy, scikit-learn, mne... where each module has its own `tests` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the unsupported regex syntax (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72524001/1551810), exclude doesn't work if the test files are included in the source distribution (sdist), e.g. because there is a `MANIFEST.in` that includes them or because of the use of the setuptools-scm package (see also https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3260).

If the tests are to be excluded from the wheel, but included in the sdist, the solution is to explicitly disable `include-package-data` (the default is `true`):

```
[tool.setuptools]
packages.find.include = ['lib*']
packages.find.exclude = ['lib*tests']
include-package-data = false
```

Comment: In case you have in addition a data folder (without `__init__.py`) you do want to include, you will have to add it explicitly with a statement like `package-data."lib.data" = ["*"]`.

Comment: Kudos for the background information on both the syntax and the use of `MANIFEST.in` and setuptools-scm.